# 'Scholarly' alternatives to Goodreads

Tags: publications, networking, reference-managers

As you can read on Wikipedia,

> Goodreads is an Amazon company and "social cataloging" website founded
>   in December 2006 and launched in January 2007 by Otis Chandler, a
>   software engineer and entrepreneur, and Elizabeth Chandler. The
>   website allows individuals to freely search Goodreads' extensive
>   user-populated database of books, annotations, and reviews. Users can
>   sign up and register books to generate library catalogs and reading
>   lists. [...] On the Goodreads website, users can add books to their
>   personal bookshelves, rate and review books, see what their friends
>   are reading, participate in discussion boards and groups on a variety
>   of topics, and get suggestions for future reading choices based on
>   their reviews of previously read books.

My question is:

> *Is there a scholarly alternative to Goodreads, that is, a website
>   where you can shelf papers, journal articles, scholarly websites, and
>   preprints as well as books?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There indeed is plenty of web sites where you can shelf articles, preprints, etc. ([Mendeley](http://mendeley.com), [Zotero](http://zotero.org), [CiteULike](http://www.citeulike.org/), and so on; a fairly comprehensive [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software#Password_.22protection.22_and_network_versions) is available on Wikipedia) but if you also would like to have the possibility of adding *reviews* like in GoodReads, the things are somewhat different.

One site that I know of that allows you to do this, in addition to merely bookmarking the items, is [ResearchGate](http://www.researchgate.net) with its [Open Review feature](http://www.researchgate.net/publicliterature.OpenReviewInfo.html), but you can only bookmark and review items that already are in their database (you can add the articles that you (co-)authored but I doubt that reviewing them is your intention). Perhaps there are some other sites with a similar functionality: e.g. [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CiteULike) CiteULike has it too; on Mendeley you can [share articles' annotations within private groups](http://www.mendeley.com/features/read-and-annotate/).

Also, there is a number of sites allowing you to bookmark and review [arXiv](http://arxiv.org) preprints (e.g. [SciRate](https://scirate.com/)) but not the other kinds of items like the books.

Answer (score -1):

http://f1000.com/prime "is composed of 5,000 Faculty Members — senior scientists and leading experts in all areas of biology and medicine — plus their associates.

The Faculty recommends the
most important articles, rating them and providing short explanations for their selections.
"

Comment: While F1000 is a great website, there are several aspects in which it does not fulfill what OP is looking for. First, only F1000 Faculty can post reviews. Second, the site is based on recommendations, so no negative reviews. Third, I think it is restricted to journal papers, and does not cover books.